# Guide to designing complex API that works in a RESTful way?

Tags: api, rest

I have tried out the RESTful API concept and found out that its a great mindset for building resources APIs. For example, adding `comment` to `post` would be

```
POST /posts/{id}/comments
```

However, there are some cases, correct me if I am wrong, that the expected APIs can not really be model as a simple CRUD

For example, adding `product` to the system requires adding `picture`, adding multiple `tags` specify its `category`?

How do I do this the restful way?

1.) Do I force the API user to follow after multiple API calls?

```
POST /pictures  -- add picture
GET /categories -- get selected category
POST /tags       -- add tags
POST /products  -- input picture, category, tags ids as JSON fields
```

2.) Do I use nested object which automatically do find all subresources?

```
POST /products -- input nested JSON array with picture/category/tags object field
```

In this case, all subresources will be existing resources instead of some (`picture`, `tags`) that should be posted.
Also, what would happen if adding `picture` succeed internally but adding `tags` failed?

3.) Do I just do a casual API? How does this fit with REST? Doesn't this break the RESTful idea?

```
POST /add_products
```

Is there any guide to deal with complex API for RESTful APIs?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, one of the biggest misconception people have about REST is that internal models (tables in db or document in mongo) and REST resources must be same. REST resources can be a real model or it can be an abstract entity as well which might not exist in db.

So in this case, your url with `POST` i.e. `POST /products` request is perfectly alright as far as REST is concerned. And advice from my personal experience - One doesn't needs to be too dogmatic about url as long as basic principles of REST are conserved such as

1. Use right HTTP verbs
2. Use right status codes
3. Cacheable architecture
4. Unique indentification of resource by url
5. Hypermedia (if you can go that far)